# Custom CSS not working in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

On my Laravel Project, i have the following CSS files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/vendors/iCheck/css/all.css') }}"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/lib.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/skins/iot_skin.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/member/custom.css') }}">
```

Class in custom.css:

```
a .active-link{
color: blue;
}
```

In blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('parts.import.excel') }}" class="active-link">@lang('nav.importexcel')</a> |
```

This class is not working! I have to style it inline to get a result.

[image]

Please let me know if you have an idea where i have to search. Thanks

Comment: have you tried `ctrl+f5` to clear the cache  ?

Comment: what if you'd wrote: a.active-link{color: blue;} (no space between)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there shouldn't be a space between `a` and `.active-link`. it should be:

```
a.active-link {
    color: blue;
}
```

The difference between `a .active-link` and `a.active-link` is subtle in code, but very important in implementation. `a .active-link` means "select an element with the `active-link` class that is inside an `<a>` element." On the other hand, `a.active-link` means "select an `<a>` element that also has the class of `active-link` on it." In your case, you want `a.active-link` since the `<a>` element is the same element that has the `active-link` class.

Secondly, you can use `!important` to ensure it gets `color: blue`

```
a.active-link {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

`!important` means that that rule (in this case setting the color to blue) will override all other `color` rules that are being applied to the targeted element. To learn more about how certain rules get applied over other rules, [CSS-Tricks has a great article on CSS Specificity.](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: You should explain your answer, why is `a .class` and `a.class` different? When use `!important`?

Comment: @Peter - If the solution worked for you, you should accept the answer. Then the poster will get his well earned rep and others will know that the issue has been resolved.